# How to align as spacebetween in system_alert_window Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I use this [system_alert_window](https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window) library for System alert window.

In the `EachRow` widget there is a property called `gravity`.

```
gravity: SAW.ContentGravity.LEFT, // RIGHT also available
```

That allows us to align a text only left side or right side. But I want a text in left side and another text in right side (as same as column widget spacebetween) how to do that ?

```
  SystemWindowBody body = SystemWindowBody(
          rows: [
            EachRow(
              columns: [
                EachColumn(
                  text: SystemWindowText(text: "Some body", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.black45),
                ),
              ],
              gravity: ContentGravity.CENTER,
            ),
          ],
          padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 12, top: 12),
        );
```

**Expected O/P**

[image]

Comment: How about using SizeBox

Comment: no bro we cannot use sizedbox in system alert window